# S-shaped nonlinearities in tanh neurons

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I have started reading [Fundamentals of Deep Learning by Nikhil Buduma](https://books.google.com/books/about/Fundamentals_of_Deep_Learning.html?id=SL0BvgAACAAJ) and I have a question regarding tanh neurons. In the book, it is stated:

> "When S-shaped nonlinearities are used, the tanh neuron is often preferred over the sigmoid neuron because it is zero-centered."

Can anyone explain me why exactly??

Comment: Somehow it has been seen if the mean of output's are 0 then an activation func' gives better results  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101560/tanh-activation-function-vs-sigmoid-activation-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be mentioned that RELU is the current activation function standard. But to answer your question:
The importance here is that it is very common to have normalized your data (e.g. using [batch normalization](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf)), then the data is centered around 0.

As @DuttaA commented, look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101560/tanh-activation-function-vs-sigmoid-activation-function) from Cross-Validated:

> Since data is centered around 0, the derivatives are higher. To see this, calculate the derivative of the tanh function and notice that [output] values are in the range [0,1].

And

> The range of the tanh function is [-1,1] and that of the sigmoid function is [0,1] Avoiding bias in the gradients. This is explained very well in [the paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf), and it is worth reading it to understand these issues.